# Скрыть(сделать невидимым) курсор в Windows 10 ГЛОБАЛЬНО ( во всей ОС, во всех программах)

Tags: c#

Вопрос звучит глупо и неэтично в какой-то мере. И, все же, как это сделать?

**Мне не нужно обьяснять почему это плохая идея. Мне нужно понять как это сделать.**

При этом НЕ МЕНЯЯ  картинку курсора на "невидимую" в настройках винды)

И, конечно же, сама мышка должна работать в штатном режиме. То есть решение "убрать курсор на невидимую позицию" не подходит. Мне нужно именно сделать невидимым курсор.

---

Upd: Решение:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int ShowCursor(bool bShow);
```

не предлагать. На Windows 10 глобально не работает. Проверьте сами :)

А

```
System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
```

работает так же исключительно в окне программы.

Comment: `ShowCursor(FALSE);`

Comment: @user7860670 пробовал, не работает)

Comment: может вы хотите скрыть в чужой программе? так это и не должно работать Может это вообще проблема XY? Зачем его скрывать когда пользователь делает что-то другое?

Comment: @user7860670, в заголовке же написано -- во всей операционной системе, во всех программах. Что до того "для чего" - это в вопросе не так важно. Я хочу допилять функционал курсора, который урезали в 10той винде. Штатными методами вопрос нерешабелен, потому приходится решать вопрос костылями.

Comment: А поменять картинку курсора на невидимую програмно - тоже нельзя? Почему?

Comment: @aepot Потому что это вмешательство в настройки ОС) Я хочу отрисовывать курсор который стоит в настройках ос вручную при этом скрывать основной курсор ОС.

Comment: Стало интнресно что Вы пытаетесь реализовать в итоге

Comment: @Stranger in the Q это секретная разработка :) автор дал явно всем это понять. Предположу, что управление инерцией или инверсией, мне тоже не понятно, как решить задачу, условий которой не знаешь.

Comment: А какой функционал курсора урезали?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ возможность изменять размер курсора. То ли в последних билдах 10тки, то ли.в LTSC. Соответственно или принудительно сидеть на том скейлинге который предлагает ось или выбрать тот который хочется но сидеть как дебил с курсором у которого ограничение до 48х48 пикселов.

Comment: В теперешней десятке сделать что-то невозможно: ни отскейлить с настроек - этот функционал урезали, ни сделать что-либо через реестр - такой информации в интернете нет - хотя проблема у многих,  ни скейлинг програмный под курсор не работает, который работал раньше - он просто размывает курсор монитора вместо того что бы скейлить, а курсор остается оригинального размера - ограничение ОС.

Comment: Перерыл и все настройки реестра что касается мыши и потратил кучу времени зря ища настройки которых уже нет в современной версии оси. Судя по интернету, раньше была настройка скейлинга вот в этом меню: https://pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/change-mouse-pointer-size-windows_10.jpg -- теперь нет , а так же были настройки скейлинга разных элементов десктопа в детальных настройках скейлинга, сейчас в детальных "настройках" исключительно доп информация. Изменить там что-либо уже невозможно.

Comment: а 48х48 для 4к монитора это издевательство.

Comment: Плохо искали... Настройки - Устройства - Мышь - (сбоку) Изменить размер курсора и указателя мыши. Попадаете в то меню, что у вас на скриншоте выше в котором делаете какой угодно себе размер курсора.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ http://prntscr.com/rphb7m yнету здесь регуляции размера как на скриншоте выше) Я ж не слепой :) Версия винды - LTSC последний билд, поставленный неделю назад.

Comment: Ну тогда у вас довольно странная OS и вам стоит наверно разобраться с ней, нежели писать костыли для повторения реализации того, что изначально должно быть в системе. Но дело конечно ваше. P.S. Win10 Pro, последний релиз - 1909 (Rus) имеет все это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не `C` отлов мыши можно реализовать с помощью глобального хука, под `C#`вероятно можно использовать через `Marshaling`. Примитивное решение, поймать мышь и перерисовать ей курсор на прозрачный/свой собственный итд.

Скелетный код хука:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE))
    {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* p = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

        HWND hiWnd = WindowFromPoint(p->pt);
        if (hiWnd)
        {
            POINT pt = p->pt;
            ...
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
     }
}
```

`LowLevelMouseProc` - чтение по теме https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: Чудно, конечно, идея хорошая. Только код не шарповский и шарп, вроде как, не поддерживает LowLevelHooks на сколько я видел в инете... А LowLevelMouseProc - LowLevelHook...

Comment: Но если бы удалость предотвратить отрисовку основного курсора на шарпе - это было бы идеальным решением. Именно тем, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

public static extern int ShowCursor(bool bShow);
```

Comment: не работает на Wndows 10

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y); while(true){SetCursorPos(0, 2100)}; Конечно это просто скрывает курсор внизу и не даёт его двигать, но может это подходит для вашей  задачи.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать курсор невидимым, но оставить возможность менять его позицию и работать с мышкой в штатном режиме. Даное решение не подходит.

Comment: @Andrew работает, но только если вызывать из UI потока с окном и прячет курсор только когда мышь над приложением.

Comment: @Andrew забыл сказать, что тестил на Window 10

Comment: @aepot То есть не глобально :) А глобально на виндовс 10 не работает.

Comment: @Andrew Ну вот вы и ответили на свой вопрос.